# Gulp – How to copy files into all subfolders of a folder

Tags: file, gulp, copy

I'd like to copy one file into each subdirectory of a directory with gulp. This code doesn't seem to do the trick, although `*` should stand for any number of characters if I am not mistaken.

```
// Copy the main.css
    gulp.src('./styles/main.css')
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./test-courses/*/'));
```

Is gulp not able to detect all subfolders itself? Is it even possible to write anything like this with Gulp?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const glob = require('glob');

// get an array of subdirectories under test-courses, 
const subDirectories = glob.sync('./test-courses/*/');

// console.dir(subDirectories);

// Copy the main.css
gulp.task('default', (done) => {

  // run the pipeline for each subDirectory

  subDirectories.forEach(function (subDirectory) {

    return gulp.src('./styles/main.css')
      .pipe(gulp.dest(subDirectory));
  });

  done();
});
```

[glob.sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob#globsyncpattern-options) returns an array.

I believe that `gulp.dest` takes a simple string (**not** a glob) or a function which returns a string so your `('./test-courses/*/')` will not work.